# SSIS - Looking Up Records from Different Databases

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a source table in a Sybase database (ORDERS) and a Source table in an MSSQL Database (DOCUMENTS). I need to query the Sybase database and for each row found in the ORDERS table get the matching row(s) by order number from the DOCUMENTS table.

I originally wrote the SSIS package using a lookup transformation, simple, except that it could be a one-to-many relationship, where 1 order number will exist in the ORDERS table but more than 1 documents could exist in the DOCUMENTS table. The SSIS lookup will only match on first.

My 2nd attempt will be to stage the rows from the ORDERS table into a staging table in MSSQL and then loop through the rows in this table using a FOR EACH LOOP CONTAINER and get the matching rows from the DOCUMENTS table, inserting the DOCUMENTS rows into another staging table. After all rows from ORDERS have been processed I will write a query to join the two staging tables to give me my result. A concern with this method is that I will be opening and closing the DOCUMENTS database connection many times, which will not be very efficient (although there will probably be less than 200 records).

Or could you let me know of any other way of doing this?

Comment: what is your end goal? you said 2 things you've tried. neither of which resulted in anything

Comment: If you staged the data in MSSQL why not just do a JOIN/DISTINCT or whatever you need in a regular SQL query instead of trying to do a lookup in a loop in SSIS? If it's only 200 records to access in the staging table, I think performance is really not a concern here. Surely the looping lookup in SSIS will consume far more resources than a simple join.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. I haven't implemented the "2nd phase" yet, I was just putting it out there to see if there is a better way to do this. The end goal is to have one list of combined orders and documents. So if I end up staging both orders and documents then I will do a simple join on the 2 staging tables to get the results that I need

Comment: Extract both tables sorted by OrderID and run through a merge (determine if outer join is need... can an order have no docs?).